# Change column names in a query dynamically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a below table,  I need to calculate the difference for Jan month as shown below.

```
StaringItemCount_<month> - EndingItemCount_<month>
```

| ItemNumber | StaringItemCount_jan | EndingItemCount_jan | StaringItemCount_feb | EndingItemCount_feb | StaringItemCount_mar | EndingItemCount_mar | StaringItemCount_apr | EndingItemCount_apr | StaringItemCount_may | EndingItemCount_may | StaringItemCount_jun | EndingItemCount_jun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BS:100331 | 100 | 80 | 200 | 0 | 300 | 150 | 200 | 100 | 300 | 200 | 120 | 20 |
| BS:100332 | 200 | 120 | 300 | 10 | 500 | 120 | 700 | 400 | 100 | 50 | 10 | 2 |
| BS:100333 | 300 | 60 | 250 | 30 | 600 | 180 | 800 | 500 | 200 | 20 | 12 | 0 |
| BS:100334 | 400 | 70 | 300 | 50 | 200 | 140 | 500 | 300 | 300 | 40 | 150 | 40 |
| BS:100335 | 500 | 120 | 500 | 70 | 100 | 350 | 300 | 200 | 600 | 60 | 140 | 139 |

I was able to solve this for two columns by using the below query.

```
select 
    *, (StaringItemCount_jan - EndingItemCount_jan) AS remainingJan 
from additionCheck
```

Now my challenge is to calculate this for every month and Do I need to repeat the same query every time? Wont it lead to code duplication as we are doing the same thing over and over again. Only change is in the column names.

Do we have any other way around where we declare the column names in a list and then put those in a loop and pass it to the select statement?

**Edits** based on the comments:

My actual problem is different. The operation which I am supposed to perform is a lag operation on a particular column and then group the rows based on the primary key. Once that is completed we then find the max value based on windows operation. The window size varies i.e 3,6,12.

My challenge is I have 18 such columns and 3 window operations. Totally, I have to copy paste for 54 times. I tried to replicate my problem on a smaller scale so that its easy to understand and also, it does not violate my organization policies.

Comment: This is (one of the reasons) why it's a bad idea to have a column for each month. You'll have to do it by hand, or use dynamic SQL. Both options are worse than remodeling (if it's a possibility)

Comment: I concur, this is a SQL Anti-Pattern.  The correct structure to match SQL's semantics is to have four columns; `ItemNumber`, `Month`, `StartingItemCount`, `EndingItemCount`.   A whole raft of queries then become MUCH simpler.

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You are going to have to edit some more, because your latest update doesn't make sense to me. Please explain it more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of achieving this is through dynamic SQL, here you can use the table properties from the system tables to access the column names in the order you need them. I haven't included the lag aspect as I'm not sure exactly what it is you need calculating but I think this should get you close.

```
create table additioncheck
(ItemNumber nvarchar(25),
 StartingItemCount_Jan int,
 EndingItemCount_Jan int,
  StartingItemCount_Feb int,
 EndingItemCount_Feb int,
  StartingItemCount_Mar int,
 EndingItemCount_Mar int,
  StartingItemCount_Apr int,
 EndingItemCount_Apr int,
  StartingItemCount_May int,
 EndingItemCount_May int,
  StartingItemCount_Jun int,
 EndingItemCount_Jun int);

 insert additioncheck (ItemNumber, StartingItemCount_Jan, EndingItemCount_Jan, StartingItemCount_Feb, EndingItemCount_Feb, StartingItemCount_Mar, 
 EndingItemCount_Mar, StartingItemCount_Apr, EndingItemCount_Apr, StartingItemCount_May, EndingItemCount_May, StartingItemCount_Jun, EndingItemCount_Jun)
 values 
 ('BS:100331', 100, 80, 200, 0, 300, 150, 200, 100, 300, 200, 120, 20), 
('BS:100332', 200, 120, 300, 10, 500, 120, 700, 400, 100, 50, 10, 2), 
('BS:100333', 300, 60, 250, 30, 600, 180, 800, 500, 200, 20, 12, 0), 
('BS:100334', 400, 70, 300, 50, 200, 140, 500, 300, 300, 40, 150, 40), 
('BS:100335', 500, 120, 500, 70, 100, 350, 300, 200, 600, 60, 140, 139)


 select * from additioncheck; /*raw data*/

 declare @sql nvarchar (max) = '';
 declare @columnlist table (id int identity(1,1), columnname sysname);
 /*build column list excluding the columns you don't want, this uses the order the columns were created in, so in theory January is to the left of February etc*/
 insert @columnlist (columnname)
 select name from sys.columns where OBJECT_ID('additioncheck') = object_id and name <> 'ItemNumber' order by column_id;

 select * from @columnlist order by id; /*check that the columns are in the correct 
 order*/

 select @sql = @sql + 'select ItemNumber, ';

 declare @i int = 1;
 /*build formulas, you can make the query here more complex by adding lag and such*/
 while exists (select 1 from @columnlist)
 begin
    declare @startcol sysname, @endcol sysname, @alias sysname;
    select @startcol = columnname from @columnlist where id = @i;
    select @endcol = columnname from @columnlist where id = @i+1;
    select @alias = 'remaining' + RIGHT(@startcol, 3);
    select @sql = @sql + '(' + @startcol + '-' + @endcol + ') as ' + @alias + ', ';
    delete from @columnlist where id in (@i, @i+1);
    select @i = @i+2;
 end

 select @sql = LEFT(@sql, len(@sql) - 1); /*remove trailing comma*/

 select @sql = @sql + ' from additioncheck;'

 exec (@sql) /*data set*/

 drop table additioncheck;
```

Comment: Careful, this is going to be pretty slow, due to the use of the `WHILE`, and *could* error or be open to injection due to the unsafe injection of object names into a dynamic statement.

Comment: Good point, although that would rely upon the query being called over the web or something similar. It could be put in to a stored procedure to avoid that. As for the slowness the while statement is only used to build the column list in to the dynamic query, not to actually calculate the data so I don't think that will be too much of an issue as the number of columns is 18 (based on OP's last edits) and (in theory) unlikely to change.

Comment: @DwightReynoldson, Sorry for the delayed response. But I when I try to run this.I am getting an error:

SQL Error [1087] [S0002]: Must declare the table variable "@columnlist".
  Must declare the table variable "@columnlist".
  Must declare the table variable "@columnlist".

Comment: @DwightReynoldson. But the variable is already defined.

Comment: @User27854 no problem for the delay, as long as you are referencing the "@columnlist" table variable in the same script that is is defined in it should run. If you try to reference the "@columnlist" table variable from another query window (i.e. another connection) it won't work. If I copy and paste that entire script in to a new query window it runs without any issue so I'm confident there isn't a syntax error there.

Comment: I copied the above script and tried running it in DBeaver.

Comment: @DwightReynoldson, I tried this in  dbfiddle.uk and it works perfectly fine. Could be something to do with my db. Need to check

Comment: Yeah it looks like in their documentation https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/SQL-Execution/ certain "@" commands are executed client side and not server side in Dbeaver which might be the issue here. I have 0 experience with Dbeaver so probably won't be much use helping you troubleshoot that product. If you are able to work with Microsoft SQL Management Studio then you should be good to go.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to repeat similar expressions:

```
select ac.*,
      (ac.StaringItemCount_jan - ac.EndingItemCount_jan) AS remainingJan,
      (ac.StaringItemCount_feb - ac.EndingItemCount_feb) AS remainingFeb,
      (ac.StaringItemCount_mar - ac.EndingItemCount_mar) AS remainingMar,
      . . .
from additionCheck ac;
```

Yes, this is code duplication.  And if you stored the data properly as separate rows for each month rather than putting the months in columns, then duplication for this calculation would not be necessary.

Comment: My actual calculation is not so simple. The operation which I am supposed to perform is a  lag operation on a single column and then group the rows based on the primary key. Then find the max value based on windows operation. The window size varies i.e 3,6,12. My challange  is I have 18 such columns and 3 window operations. Totally, I have to copy paste for 54 times. So, I was checking if there is a workaround.

Comment: I cant but the actual problem here as that would a violation of my organization policy.

Comment: @User27854 . . . If you have another calculation, you should ask a *new* question, with a clear explanation.  This answers the question asked here.

Comment: @User27854 Maybe not do that in sql then? Sometimes, problems become harder in SQL compared to imperative programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Your need to dynamically access column names in this way most likely points to bad table design.  Instead of having separate columns for each month, consider just maintaining a single date column which keeps tracks of the months:

```
ItemNumber | StaringItemCount | EndingItemCount | Date
BS:100331  | 100              | 80              | 2021-01-01
BS:100331  | 200              | 0               | 2021-02-01
BS:100331  | 300              | 150             | 2021-03-01
BS:100331  | 200              | 100             | 2021-04-01
BS:100331  | 300              | 200             | 2021-05-01
BS:100331  | 120              | 20              | 2021-06-01
...
```

Now if you wanted to filter on records only occurring within January, you can just use a dynamic *date literal*, e.g.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE Date = '2021-01-01';  -- change this for other months; keep columns the same
```

Comment: My actual calculation is not so simple. The operation which I am supposed to perform is a lag operation on a particular column and then group the rows based on the primary key. Then find the max value based on windows operation. The window size varies i.e 3,6,12. My challange is I have 18 such columns and 3 window operations. Totally, I have to copy paste for 54 times. So, I was checking if there is a workaround.

Comment: I cant put my exact tables etc here as it would be a violation of my organization policy

Comment: @User27854 - That's the single worst excuse available.  It means you don't understand your problem well enough to mock up example data, or are not willing to make enough effort to provide it.  I strenuously suggest you read this : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @MatBailie, If I dont understand the problem, I wont be able to post a question on it. I have spent good amount of time to come up with an example and post it it. So just saying  that I have not put any effort is an understatement. If that is not meeting your expectation, Then I am sorry.

Comment: @User27854 - If you understand the problem and are willing to make the effort, there's never a conflict with organisational privacy policy.  As Per The Link I Cited.